# Magento set Cookie?

Tags: product, cookie

We need to show recently viewed product by customer based on browser and i try to below code.

```
    $cookie = Mage::getSingleton('core/cookie');

    if ($cookie->get('recent_product')) { 
        $recent_product = $cookie->get('recent_product'); 
        $Current_prd = explode(",",$cookie->get('recent_product'));

        if (!in_array($productId, $Current_prd)) {
            $recent_product=$recent_product.",".$productId;   
        }
        # $cookie->get('recent_product');
        $cookie->set('recent_product', $recent_product ,time()+86400,'/');
    } else { 
        $recent_product =array();
        $recent_product=$productId;
        $cookie = Mage::getSingleton('core/cookie');
        $cookie->set('recent_product',$recent_product ,time()+86400,'/');
    }
```

It is set the cookie. But when i close the browser, not able to get the previous cookie value.

What i missing the above code?.

Answer (score 3):

Finally I get the solution. Just removed the `time()` key.

```
$cookie = Mage::getSingleton('core/cookie');

if ($cookie->get('recent_product')) { 
    $recent_product = $cookie->get('recent_product'); 
    $Current_prd = explode(",",$cookie->get('recent_product'));

    if (!in_array($productId, $Current_prd)) {
        $recent_product=$recent_product.",".$productId;   
    }
    # $cookie->get('recent_product');
    $cookie->set('recent_product', $recent_product ,86400,'/');
} else { 
    $recent_product =array();
    $recent_product=$productId;
    $cookie = Mage::getSingleton('core/cookie');
    $cookie->set('recent_product',$recent_product ,86400,'/');
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your code works in principle; something is off with your display logic:

```
<?php
ini_set('display_errors',true);
error_reporting(E_ALL | E_STRICT);
require 'app/Mage.php';
Mage::setIsDeveloperMode(true);
umask(0);
Mage::app();

/* @var $cookie Mage_Core_Model_Cookie */
$cookie = Mage::getSingleton('core/cookie');

if ($cookie->get('recent_product')) {
    var_dump($cookie->get('recent_product'));
}
else {
    $cookie = Mage::getSingleton('core/cookie');
    $cookie->set('recent_product','foo' ,time()+86400,'/');
}
```

Looking further, shouldn't your `else` use `implode()` based on how you are processing it in the `if`?

```
} else { 
    $recent_product = array();
    $recent_product = $productId;
    $cookie = Mage::getSingleton('core/cookie');
    $cookie->set('recent_product',implode(',',$recent_product) ,time()+86400,'/');
}
```